# My C# window application cannot insert new record to sql database both in ADO.net and Entity Framework

Tags: c#-4.0

Good day people! I have a problem with my C# window application. 
I can't insert new record to database. I have sought for many tutorial in ADO.net and Entity Framework. 
I have been tackling it in Entity Framework because that is my preference. 
My piece of Entity Framework code would run successfully to insert new record. 
When i go back-end to see the result; none is found.I am using Visual studio 2010.
 And i developed the database through visual studio (the normal way of adding new item). 
I have this piece of code:

public bool CreateStaff(string txtUserName, string gender, string txtProfession, string txtMobilePhone, string txtAddress)
            {
                //using (MyHospDataEntities db = new MyHospDataEntities())
                //{
                try
                {
                    StaffData addstaff = new StaffData();

```
                addstaff.StaffName = txtUserName;
                addstaff.Sex = gender;
                addstaff.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
                addstaff.Profession = txtProfession;
                addstaff.PhoneNumber = txtMobilePhone;
                addstaff.Address = txtAddress;
                mms.StaffDatas.AddObject(addstaff);
                mms.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                throw new Exception("ERROR: Unable to Add Staff - " + exp.Message.ToString(), exp);
            }
            //}
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Is the exception thrown?

Answer (score 1):

"mms" this is DbContext?

You can try this

`mms.StaffDatas.Add(new StaffDatas {});`

mms.SaveChanges();

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your *connection string* is correct. Some times the *connection string* like this

> "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename="+Application.StartupPath +"Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"

give you the same problem if you have `.exe` and `database file` are same in runtime and in `bin/debug` folder.